# search for partial id and change value

Tags: javascript

I want to search for a input where part of the ID name is `searchID` ( dynamic ) plust a static `_conf`  something like  `center_forehead_conf`

Then I want to set that value to true.

```
$jointlist.find("input[id*=searchID+'_conf']").val(true);
```

but im getting a
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id*=searchID+'_conf']`

If I search for

```
$jointlist.find("input[id*='_conf']").val(true);
```

it works fine, but it changes ALL the id's containing a `_conf` to true

Comment: This question is about string concatenation in javascript it seems, if searchId is a variable you should do something like  $jointlist.find("input[id*=" + searchID + "_conf]")

Comment: Yep, you are correct.  Thanks